# How to count the number of elements which contains one or more identical class attributes using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

[image]

In this code, how can I count the `full ng-scope` class? except `empty ng-scope`

Please help.

Comment: How did you try? Share more issue details

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Also include the code you have tried and what the result was including any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *count* the number of elements with *class* attribute as `full ng-scope` , you can use the following solution:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.star-point>span.total span.full.ng-scope")))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='star-point']/span[@class='total']//span[@class='full ng-scope']")))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of elements with a particular class, you do :

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('your_class_name'))
```

`driver.find_elements` returns a list of elements matching with the particular locator and so `len()` of that list will be the number of such elements.

In your case, since your class name contains spaces, its better to use xpath :

```
count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='full ng-scope']"))
```

**In this code, how can I count the full ng-scope class? except empty ng-scope**

The above locator will exactly match the string locator you passed, so it will only search for `full ng-scope` and not `empty ng-scope`.

Comment: It would actually be better to use a CSS selector, `span.full.ng-scope`. Using an XPath locator like this is doing a string match for `'full ng-scope'` so if the classes ever changed order or if another class was inserted between the two, the XPath locator would fail while the CSS selector would still work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS selector

```
span.full.ng-scope
```

will work here. It will match all `SPAN`s that have both the `full` and `ng-scope` classes which will exclude any elements that contain the class `empty`.

You want to avoid using an XPath like

```
//span[@class='full ng-scope']
```

because it's doing an exact string match on the class as `'full ng-scope'` so if a new CSS class is added, that locator will fail. If the two class names get swapped, it will fail. In all cases, the CSS selector will still work. It will lessen the chance that you will have to maintain/update the locator later.